# SSMS - How to Enable Word Wrap for Messages Pane

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Sometimes I need to take screen shots of error messages in SQL Server. How can I turn on word wrap in the messages pane so I can capture all the text in the screen shot?

[image]

Comment: why do you need screenshots? In most cases the raw text is more useful as it is searchable or easy to copy and paste from if researching the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an option to enable word wrap in the messages pane.  You *can* enable for the text editor window (through Tools -> Options -> Text Editors), but that doesn't really help in your situation.

In case you didn't know, though, you *can* click into that messages pane and edit the text.  So you could insert the line breaks yourself.  Not ideal, but good enough to get the desired screenshot.

Before:

[image: long string of text cut off in messages pane]

After manual editing:

[image: long string of text edited to fit in messages pane]

I checked Azure Data Studio as well, it does not have a word wrap feature for output messages either.